# I want to make a split using 'Case When Like' (SQL)

Tags: sql

```
Select
OrderDate,
OrderID,
CafeName
(Case When Text Like '%Beer%' and Text Like '%Water%' THEN 'Beer-Water') END AS İcecek
From Food
```

I have a  sql table named 'Food'

| OrderDate | Order ID | Cafe Name | Text |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2.3.2021 | 1556 | X Cafe | Wrap, Water, Beer |
| 1.4.2021 | 3256 | Y Cafe | Carrot,Lemon, Sweercorn, Tea, Sprite |
| 2.2.2020 | 1489 | Z Cafe | Lemon, Souse, Soda,Cola |
| 1.14.2019 | 4523 | A Cafe | Brad, Lemon, Sweet Corn, Beer, Soda |
| 1.8.2020 | 1248 | Y Cafe | Salt, Hot Pepper, Wine, Water |

There are 7 different kinds of drinks

‘Text’ Column contains 2 of 7 different drinks.

I can't do this using 28 When Case.
Is there a shorter way?

I need a drink pair for every order

Can you help me?

I want to this table as result

| OrderDate | Order ID | Cafe Name | Drink |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2.3.2021 | 1556 | X Cafe | Water - Beer |
| 1.4.2021 | 3256 | Y Cafe | Tea - Sprite |
| 2.2.2020 | 1489 | Z Cafe | Soda- Cola |
| 1.14.2019 | 4523 | A Cafe | Beer -Soda |
| 1.8.2020 | 1248 | Y Cafe | Wine - Water |

Comment: I don't understand your question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: "SQL" will most definitely allow you to write more than 20 `WHEN` conditions.

Comment: Is there a shorter way? Because have to write 28 when case

Comment: Show some sample data and desired results as tables in your post, not images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
Select
OrderDate,
OrderID,
CafeName,
(Case When Text Like '%Beer%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Beer,
(Case When Text Like '%Water%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Water,
(Case When Text Like '%Wine%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Wine,
(Case When Text Like '%Cola%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Cola,
(Case When Text Like '%Soda%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Soda,
(Case When Text Like '%Tea%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Tea,
(Case When Text Like '%Sprite%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Sprite,
FROM Food
```